# Flutter TextFormField onSaved no called when not visible on screen

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField inside the ListView and I found a problem that the onsaved callback never called when the TextFormField is not on screen. I plan to save the value manually using the TextEditingController but is it a good way to go?

Here some snippet code :

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Title"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: () {
              _formKey.currentState.save();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          children: List<int>.generate(30, (index) => index).map((v) {
            return TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Input $v"),
              onSaved: (v1) => print("On save $v called"),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The "On save $v called" printed not for all field.

Comment: Do you have some code to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, so instead of using ListView, I use SingleChildScrollView.